# Groovy - XmlSlurper - find innermost element

Tags: groovy, xmlslurper

I have the following xml:

```
<vehicle>
  <car>
    <price>100</price>
    <price>200</price>
  </car>
  <car>
    <price>300</price>
    <price>400</price>
  </car>
</vehicle>
```

Given an xml, how can we get the innermost elements (in this case, all the`<price>` elements)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thanks Tim for the answer. I just figured out the following works too. And is more generic:

```
def document = slurper.parseText(xml)
def prices = document.'**'.findAll { it.children().size() == 0 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have the xml in a String `xml`, you should be able to do:

```
List prices = new XmlSlurper().parseText( xml ).car.price*.text()​​
```

Answer (score 0):

May I suggest you next variant:

```
def vehicle = new XmlSlurper().parseText(xmlString)
vehicle.car.price.each {println "car's price:"+it}
```

Comment: IMHO topic starter was meant that xml structure is unknown. Your answer assumes you know exact xml structure.

Comment: Mm, probably I didn't get it from question