# How to get all the XML nodes and its values from a XML with groovy?

Tags: groovy

I have an XML like below.

```
xml1 = '''
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soap>
    <group1>
        <g1node1>g1value1</g1node1>
        <g1node2>g1value2</g1node2>
        <g1node3>g1value3</g1node3>
    </group1>
    <group2 attr="attrvalue1">
        <g2node1>g2value1</g2node1>
        <g2node2>g2value2</g2node2>
        <g2node3>g2value3</g2node3>
    </group2>
</soap>
'''
```

Here, i need to get all the xml node and its values as output, either as line by line result and as a list with groovy. The output should look like

```
g1node1 = g1value1
g1node2 = g1value2
... and so on...
```

or either with a groovy map like below

```
out = [g1node1 : "g1value1", g1node2 : "g1value2", ...and so on...]
```

can anyone help me how to achieve this with groovy code?

Comment: Can you show the code you've tried?

Comment: I think this question is pretty similar http://stackoverflow.com/q/23632849/2504101. Take a look at the answers offered.

Answer (score 0):

I would still like to know (as Tim mentioned) what you have tried yet, but here is my itch:

```
def result = new XmlSlurper().parseText( xml )
result.'**'.collectEntries { !it.childNodes() ? [ it.name(), it.text() ] : [:] }
```

Comment: I am new to groovy and i have tried like below. I googled and find out the keyword 'collectEntries'. But could not get to what i need.

    xml1 = new File("C:\\junk\\a.txt").text
    def xmlParser = new XmlParser()
    out = xmlParser.parseText(xml1)
    out.'**'.collectEntries{
        println it.text()
    }

and i got the below exception and i know the code is wrong.

     g1value1g1value2g1value3g2value1g2value2g2value3
     Exception thrown
     
     java.lang.NullPointerException
     
 at ConsoleScript62.run(ConsoleScript62:6)

Comment: **@dmahapatro**

Thanks for your time and help. I tried your code and it works and the result shows like below

> [g1node1:g1value1, g1node2:g1value2, g1node3:g1value3, g2node1:g2value1, g2node2:g2value2, g2node3:g2value3]

I have 2 questions.

1. Is it possible to have the values in (double quotes) ""?.
2. When i execute the same code in SoapUI (its my automation tool), i get an nullpointer exception on the line where i use "out.'**'.collectEntries {..."

can you please help me?